# Git: Best way to manage multiple working copies of a single repo with third-party remote?

Tags: git

Generally, I am trying to figure out how to sync my changes to a third-party lib across multiple arch builds for that lib.

Specifically, I am managing four clones of the main Qt git repo (as in with a remote on qt.io), one for each lib architecture I build for my app. For example, I have separate qt release builds for iOS, iPhoneSimulator, macOS, windows and one debug build for development.

The problem is that I am modifying the qt source code and want to sync and test these changes across all of my working copies, while still being able to push to the main Qt repo on qt.io.

How do I set this up with git? Do I need to setup my own bare repo as a second remote or something? How does this work?

Thanks!

Comment: There are many ways to do this. For simple cases, provided your Git is new enough, I like `git worktree add`; but your case may be more complicated. Whether you need or want a bare repository is up to you. You can use pure-pull workflows where, to work on the laptop, you `git pull` from somewhere, then over on the Windows box you `git pull` from the laptop, and so on. (I do this with BSD-and-MacOS.)

Comment: Interesting. I have been using git for a while but never really learned how to do any of this. Can you give a more step by step example or link to one? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can pull branches from one working copy to another by setting a remote in  to /.git which is actually a bare repo. I suppose you learn something every day. Say you have two qt builds, one for iOS and one for OS X, and you have a branch of commits in the iOS copy you want to pull to the OS X copy:

```
cd qt-ios
git checkout -b some-branch
git commit -a -m "made changes"
cd qt-osx
git remote add qt-ios ../qt-ios/.git
git pull qt-ios some-branch
```

that's it. Then theoretically you could do the same in the other direction.

Comment: You should be able to use just `../qt-ios` for a case like this one, but either way is fine. That's not a *bare* repository (a bare repository has `core.bare` set to `true`), it's just "a repository". A *remote*, in Git, is just a short name for a URL, and a URL can be `ssh://`, or `http` or `https` based, or `file://`, or even just a path name. In all cases, `fetch`ing from the remote means "call up another Git" (perhaps by spinning one up on your own computer!) "and talk with it".